# Why my app requesting media permission when installing?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I released my application in Google Play and when trying to install it it requesting access to Media although I didn't set that in the Manifest file

Here are my permissions in the Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

when in installing my app from the phone it asks from media access:

[image]

but when I open my app in the desktop browser it doesn’t show Media permission with the other permissions:

[image]

Comment: This is weird. You are sure there is no `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` here or there?

Comment: @DerGolem Libraries can't add permissions on its own.

Comment: @hegazy Yes there was WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my app but i removed it and updated my app yesterday but Google Play still requesting Media access when trying to install it so i cleared it's cache and tried again and it's no longer requesting that permission . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There was `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my app but i removed it and updated my app yesterday but Google Play still requesting Media access when trying to install it so i cleared Google Play's cache and tried again and now it doesn't request that permission any more . Thank you